# Apache Tiles 3.x doesn't anymore compile in Spring 6.x because javax.* renamed to jakarta.*

Tags: spring, apache-tiles, jakarta-migration

My application uses Spring 5.x,Apache Tiles 3.0.x. Now I would like to migrate to Spring 6.x but the problem is with Apache Tiles 3.0.x because it has javax.servlet.* instead of jakarta.* . All spring 6.x has packages with Jakarta.* . so what should i do with Apache tiles when i want to migrate my application to Spring 6?

I tried replacing Spring 5.x jars with Spring 6.x jars and found errors with javax.servlet and able to resolve some errors but i am unable to resolve errors apache tiles 3.0.x package

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tiles has retired in about 2018 - that means that you don't get updates since that date. This could be dangerous as you also didn't get security updates since then. (See also its [attic page](https://attic.apache.org/projects/tiles.html))

So I see two main options for you:

- Either you fork the Apache Tiles project and fix the wrong namespaces yourself
- Or you switch your application to a different dependency (see e.g. [Apache Tiles retired. Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144131/apache-tiles-retired-alternatives))

Please don't consider to stay on your current setup of Java and/or Spring versions as this will rise even more potential security problems.